# Is the cardinality of an empty set comparable to some other sets by the definition?

Tags: analysis, set-theory, cardinals

I've been learning mathematical analysis written by B.A Zorich recently. The description of Card X ≤ Card Y in this book is "there exists a bijective mapping of X onto some subset of Y". But here comes my question: if X is an empty set, it is well known that the inequality Card X ≤ Card Y holds (Y is an nonempty set here), but is there an bijective mapping of X onto some subset of Y? I mean X is empty, how can we construct the bijective? Incidentally, my English is poor, if I don't make myself clear, please just tell me, I'll try to express it more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $X=\emptyset$. Consider the identity function $\text{id}\colon X\to\emptyset$. It is clear that $\emptyset\subseteq Y$ and that $\text{id}$ is a bijection, because it is vacously injective and surjective.

Comment: Was this clear?  Stated in words.: One of the subsets of $Y$ is the empty set.  The identity function from the empty set $X$ to the empty subset of $Y$ is a bijection. To understand this, you need to understand the quantifiers "for all" and "there exists", in particular as they are used  in the definition of "bijection".

Comment: @GEdgar I'll edit my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but the definition of a "function" given in the book is "by virtue of some rule f, to each element x € X there corresponds an element y € Y", the domain of definition X here is an empty set in this context, so there should be no element in X. I still can't understand the expression "to each element x € empty set".@closedrhombus

Comment: @Erutaner This is why id is a function: For the sake of contradiction, suppose that id is not a function. According to the definition given in the book you quoted, there would exist x in X such that no element y in Y corresponds to x, but given that X is empty, no such x can exist. But still, the definition given in the book is not the typical one that is used in set theory.

Comment: @Erutaner The definition of a function $f:X\to{Y}$ is that $f\subset{X\times{Y}}$ such that $\forall{x\in{X}},\exists{\mathrm{exactly\;one}\;y},(x,y)\in{f}.$ Since $X=\emptyset,$ this is a matter of understanding what it means to say $\forall{x\in\emptyset}.$ If you have a proposition $A(x)$ with a free variable $x,$ then the first-order sentence $\forall{x\in\emptyset}\;A(x)$ is equivalent to the logical constant $\top.$ This is to say, the sentence is trivially true. Its negation is trivially false. This is what closedrhombus is referencing in his comment.

Comment: @Erutaner Also, I should point out that the empty set is unique.

Comment: Thank you both very much, I get it now. We can find a function whose domain is the empty set (identity here), so there's nothing unclear now.

Comment: @Erutaner If it was helpful, I'd really appreciate it if you accepted my answer.